# Proof of existence of intersection of non-empty family from the scheme axiom of comprehension

Tags: set-theory

I am reading Cori's and Lascar's second volume of "Mathematical Logic". They give the scheme axiom of comprehension :

[image]

saying then we can define subsets $v_{n+2}$ of $v_{n+1}$ by formulas $F(v_0nv_1,\ldots,v_n)$ with variable $v_0$ are parameters $v_1,\ldots,v_n$. They use it then to prove the existence of the intersection of a non empty family of sets :

[image]

There are two things I don't understand. The first is the equivalence of the two formulas

[image]

and

[image]

The second thing I don't understand is where my error is when I try a direct proof without using their set $c$ (that is, without using that $a$ is non empty): take $n = 2$, and $P(v_0,v_1,v_2) = "\forall v_2, \left( v_2 \in v_1 \Rightarrow v_0 \in v_2 \right)"$ and apply the scheme axiom of comprehension with $v_1 = a$ ensuring that : \begin{equation}
\exists v_3, \forall v_0, \left( v_0 \in v_3 \right) \Leftrightarrow \left( \forall v_2, \left( v_2 \in v_1 \Rightarrow v_0 \in v_2 \right) \right)
\end{equation} is true. Then $v_3$ is the set we are looking for, and is unique by the axiom of extensionality (two sets are equal if and only if they have the same elements.) My proof is obviously false as if $a = v_1 = \varnothing$ we see that the previous statement implies that $v_3$ contains all sets which is a paradox in $\textrm{Z}^{-}$ (the theory with axiom of extensionality, pairs, unions, power set, comprehension).

Comment: What you wrote down isn't an instance of the axiom scheme of comprehension (unless we mean the unrestricted, inconsistent version that leads to Russel's paradox).  That "$v_0\in v_{n+1}\land$" before the $F[v_0,\ldots v_n]$ is pretty crucial and it doesn't seem to appear in what you wrote down.

Answer (score 1):

Intuitively, we want to define the set containing all sets with the property $F(v_0)=\forall v_3(v_3\in a\to v_0\in v_3)$ (which we can abbreviate using the standard $\forall v_3\in a(v_0\in v_3)$), but the problem is that comprehension does not actually allow us to do this, since it only allows us to define subsets of a given set ([for good reason](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russell%27s_paradox)!). So we need to change this unbounded comprehension into a bounded comprehension. This is what the set $c\in a$ is for: $\cap a$ will be a subset of any given set in $a,$ so if $c\in a,$ we have $$ \{v_0:F(v_0)\}=\{v_0\in c:F(v_0)\}$$ and the latter is something that is guaranteed to be a set by the comprehension axiom.

So the reason why $\forall v_3\in a(v_0\in v_3)$ is equivalent to $v_0\in c\land \forall v_3\in a(v_0\in v_3)$ is just that: if a set is in the intersection of $a$ then the fact that it is in some given set $c\in a$ is just extraneous information. More formally, if $\forall v_3\in a(v_0\in v_3)$ holds then since $c\in a,$ we can instantiate this to $v_0\in c,$ and thus we have $v_0\in c\land \forall v_3\in a(v_0\in v_3).$ The other direction of the equivalence is trivial.

Your error is that you have ignored the part of the comprehension axiom where we bound the comprehension by a set (as I said in more detail in the comments). As such, what you wrote down isn't an instance of comprehension, rather an instance of *unrestricted* comprehension, so it should come as no surprise that it results in a contradiction. Yes, naively the intersection of the empty set should contain all sets (since every set satisfies $F(v_0)$ when $a=\emptyset$) but as you say, a set of all sets can't exist. But if you can only use the (bounded) comprehension axiom you can't define the intersection operation on the empty set so you don't wind up with a contradiction.

(Or rather you can't define it in a way that comports with the fact that morally, the intersection of the empty set should be "everything". For the sake of having a total operation, I've seen some authors define $\cap \emptyset =\emptyset$, which is gross, but you have to handle this issue somehow.)

Comment: Imagine taking unrestricted comprehension (and replacement) instead of restricted ones. Using them would define something we would classically call classes, but may be sets as well depending on which formulas we use. (All vector spaces not having a zero element (characterized by 1st order formula) gives the empty class which is (should be) as set.) If this unrestricted setup, is there a way to tell sets from classes ? I mean, what is usually done in this case ?

Comment: The thing is you don’t know, and you have to prove it is a set by some means. For a theory that takes this approach quite literally, look up NBG. It has classes as formal objects, a comprehension scheme for defining them, a predicate that says a class is a set (which is just to say it is an element of some class), and the analogues of the ZF axioms can be viewed as saying certain classes are sets. It is also conservative over ZFC in the sense that it can’t prove any new theorems only about sets.